# Change background image with user wish

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I would like to create an app in which user can set background image by his own wish like Whatsapp background image during chat.

when user clicks on a button, he is promoted to select image from gallery and then that image is set as app background Image.

I have created `constraintview` for that but don't know how to do further.

Comment: Please google it.. there are billions of posts/questions/articles about it.. if you want to post on SO, you have 1st to search, 2nd to try, 3rd to try again and again anda again and finally you can ask here, posting some code, what is working, what is not and we can help you. this is NOT a "do this for me" site. For that you can hire a programmer

Comment: yes it have but not work for me

Comment: so add what you tried :)

Answer (score 1):

**If client-server**

1. Pick an image.
2. Send it to a server and save in a storage and put image url's(server) into a field in a DB.
3. At each getting of the information about user downlod iamge by url and set it as a background.

**If not client-server**

1.Pick image and cache it.

2.Every time app starts get this image from cache and set as background.

> Image Picker https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7023
>
> For http requests http://square.github.io/retrofit/
>
> To cache https://github.com/lowlevel-studios/storo

Sorry for some gramma mistakes in advance.